# Perl: Bareword "exp_continue" in the lib Net::SSH::Expect

Tags: perl, ssh, expect.pm

I am new in Perl. I downloaded the library `Net::SSH::Expect` `v.1.09` and tried to use it by example.

When I try to execute a script I get the message:

> Bareword "exp_continue" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /hom/perl/Net/SSH/Expect.pm line 203.

Comment: @SiKing, The error isn't in his code. It's a compile error from a CPAN module. The code is [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BNEGRAO/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pm).

Answer (score 1):

Net::SSH::Expect uses [Expect](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc?Expect), which exports `exp_continue` to Net::SSH::Expect.

Or at least it's suppose to. Either you have a version of Expect far older than the one indicated as Net::SSH::Expect's prerequisite, or the Expect.pm Perl finds isn't the module found on CPAN. (One of your own modules, perhaps?)

If it's the former problem, upgrade Expect. If it's the later problem, rename your module.